# App Store Review Guideline: 12.1 - Integrate Itunes Podcasts

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I´m currently checking the App Store Review Guidelines and I´m stuck at "Scraping and aggregation". Guideline 12.1 says

*"Apps that scrape any information from Apple sites (for example from apple.com, iTunes Store, App Store, iTunes Connect, Apple Developer Programs, etc.) or create rankings using content from Apple sites and services will be rejected"*

I´m parsing information from Itunes to get the playlinks, artwork-urls and titles of specific podcasts to integrate them in my own player in my app. I have a label saying that this content is provided by Itunes. Does this offend the rule mentioned above? My app also has plenty of other functionalities so its NOT just a duplication of the "Podcast"-app. But I guess it would be a "scraping" right? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

So you don't get the info from Apple's RSS?

Apple's RSS is the "good" source to show data about albums, play links, etc. The problem exists if you take that information by inspecting their websites.

Here you have some info: https://rss.itunes.apple.com/

Comment: thanks, yeah thats my source. I parse the rss feed but then I parse the podcast-ids out of the xml. Then I take the ids, combine them with the itunes-webpage link and parse them out of there. Like from a page like that:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-invisibilia-podcast/id953290300?mt=2&ign-mpt=uo%3D2

Eventually I get urls ending with .mp3 which my player is playing (With a annotation that the content comes from Itunes. Is this an issue?

Comment: You are not scraping any website with that method. There should be any problem, since you only use info from the xml

Comment: Yeah that's it. You shouldn't have any problem. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @tyler did you build it? Did you submit it? How did it go? I'd like to work on something like this, please update if this worked for you.

Comment: @jungledev yes it worked for me! The app went through the review process of apple (randomize-app.com). Message me if you have further questions!